# Как вычислить среднее арифметическое в каждой строке матрицы?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Требуется выделить память для матрицы динамически и заполнить ее
случайными числами, вычислить среднее арифметическое в каждой строке матрицы. Память выделил, заполнил её случайными числами, как сделать вычисление средней арифметической каждой строчки - не могу сообразить.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int N;
    int M;
    int  sum = 0;

    cout << "Введите количество строк матрицы: " << endl;
    cin >> N;

    cout << "Введите количество столбцов матрицы: " << endl;
    cin >> M;


    /*_____________________________*/

    int **arr = new int*[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[M];
    }

    /*_____________________________*/

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 20;
        }
    }

    /*_____________________________*/

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    /*_____________________________*/

    /*_____________________________*/

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }


    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Среднеарифметическое - сумма всех членов множества деленная на их кол-во. Исходя из этого:

```
float averageRow;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    averageRow = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        averageRow += arr[i][j];
    }
    averageRow /=M;
    cout <<"Average row " << i <<": " << averageRow <<  endl;
 }
```